# Firebase Realtime Database DATA_ACCESS audit logs logs are not visible in GCP Logging

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-logging

I have a real time database and having multiple listeners on it. I would like to see a log entry in my audit logs when a read happens.(my listeners are reading out the database when some changes occur).

Google Cloud Audit logs are the best candidate for that so I have enabled all the entries related to Firebase Realtime Database API:
[image: audit_logs]

I am the owner of the project so I am not lacking of any permissions. I would like to see who has read my database. My listeners have read for sure but I can not see those events in the logs. I can see the following log entries but none of them are the ones I would like to see:
[image]

Could you please tell me how could I see the actual reading of my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Sai for the pointers on Data Access Logs (or Cloud Audit Logs) enablement.

Just want to chime in from Firebase Realtime Database's perspective.

You have already found our documentation page: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/cloud-audit-logging/firebase-realtime-database#enabling_audit_logging

Note that there can be up to 1h of delay between audit logs IAM configs change and your databases picks up the change.

Also keep in mind that RTDB cloud audit logs only include listen registration event, update broadcast are omitted.
For more details, see [compare audit logs with profiler](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/cloud-audit-logging/firebase-realtime-database#correlate_cloud_audit_logs_with_profiler_results) documentation.